# Reflection: How to get base method (not original method)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
class A {
    public virtual void Func() { }
}

class B : A {
    public override void Func() => base.Func();
}

class C : B {
    public override void Func() => base.Func();
}


var type = typeof( C );
var method = type.GetMethod( "Func" );
method.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType.Name // A
method.GetRuntimeBaseDefinition().DeclaringType.Name // A
```

`GetBaseDefinition` returns method of A class. But I need method of B class.

Is it possible?

Comment: Well, the code asks who declares the method, and A declares it, not B. Why would you want B?

Comment: Some reason you can't just use `typeof(B).GetMethod("Func")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Walking inheritance tree

You could use some reflection and walk inheritence tree of given type, type by type:

```
public static Type GetMethodDeclaringTypeClosestInHierarchy(MethodInfo derivedTypeMethod)
{
    //Method is not virtual, you have the only definition in inheritance tree
    if (!derivedTypeMethod.IsVirtual) return derivedTypeMethod.DeclaringType;

    var baseType = derivedTypeMethod.DeclaringType.BaseType;

    while (baseType != null)
    {
        //Check if in base type there is a method
        if (baseType.GetMethods().Any(baseTypeMethod =>
            //that has same base definition like then one we're checking
            baseTypeMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == derivedTypeMethod.GetBaseDefinition()
            //and is actually overriden in baseType
            && baseTypeMethod.DeclaringType == baseType))
        {

            return baseType;
        }
        //If not, go on higher in inheritance tree
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }

    //Found nothing
    return derivedTypeMethod.DeclaringType;
}
```

### Ambiguous method name

Problem with Scott's answer is that when you have two methods with different signatures but same name in inheritance tree:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Func() { }
    public virtual string Func(string test) { return ""; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string Func(string test) => base.Func(test);
    public override void Func() => base.Func();
}

class C : B
{
    public override void Func() => base.Func();
}
```

you will get an `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'` on

```
typeof(B).GetMethod("Func",
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

### Usage

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var type = typeof(C);

    //This will throw with multiple methods of given name:
    var method1 = type.GetMethod("Func");

    //This will not but you need to be pretty explicit on what you're searching for
    var method2 = type.GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Func" && m.ReturnType == typeof(void));

    var result = GetMethodDeclaringTypeClosestInHierarchy(method2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an inheritance relationship between `A`, `B`, and `C`. But there's no such relationship between methods in the various classes. `C` isn't overriding a method in `B` - it's overriding a method in `A`. That's why the method won't give you any base definition other than the one where it was first declared.

[MethodInfo.GetBaseDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.getbasedefinition)

> ... returns the MethodInfo object for the method on the direct or indirect base class in which the method represented by this instance was **first declared**.

If you want to find the implementation of that method that is used in `C`'s immediate base class (whether or not it is declared there or inherited) then you would find out what that type is and look for the method there.

```
var type = typeof(C);
var baseType = type.BaseType;
var method = baseType.GetMethod("Func");
```

If a method is found, it isn't necessarily declared in `B`. Nothing says that `B` must have that method. If it doesn't the above will return the method from `A`.

If you want *only* what's declared in `B` then you would do this:

```
var method = baseType.GetMethod("Func", 
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

`DeclaredOnly` means that it must be declared in `B`, not inherited by `B`.

Now you'll get the method from `B` if there is one, or null if it's not overridden in `B`.

Comment: Good idea. However, you can end up with `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException` when two methods of same name but different signatures will be found (see my answer).

Comment: Ofc with author's approach of `var method = type.GetMethod( "Func" );` he will get same exception anyway. :)

Comment: Correct. I was sidestepping that since it didn't seem to be directly related. I can't really see a scenario where I'm using reflection to select a method by its name alone and trusting that it will have the right signature and no overloads. If I know that there's only one method and that it has the signature I need then it would make less sense to use reflection in the first place.